# How can I compare a list of RectangleF?

Tags: vb.net, list, overriding, comparable, rectangles

I would like to sort a List(Of RectangleF) somehow.

It is going to be huge, so I would rather not have to create a separate class that implements Comparable -

Is it possible to somehow override the RectangleF itself, to add a Comparable, and ovverride a CompareTo to compare by X ?

I am using VB.NET, but I would appreciate C# advice as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `OrderBy` methods to sort however you choose.

For example, if you want to order the list by X, you could do:

```
Dim orderedByX = theList.OrderBy(Function(rect) rect.X)
```